# JavaScript diceRoller only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, browser

The code below only works with google chrome, if I try to use any other browser it just wont work. I suspect it has something to do with the datatype I'm sending to php. However, I'm not entirely sure.

Link to where the code is hosted: http://coldrepublic.com/diceRoller(1).html

Code:

PHP

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST['data']))
    { $data = $_POST['data']; 
    $file = 'log.txt';
    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = $data;
    // Append a roll to the file
    $current .= file_get_contents($file);
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file,$current);
}
else{
    $file = 'log.txt';
    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = "No Value sent\n";
    // Append a new person to the file
    $current .= file_get_contents($file);
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
}
```

?>

Javascript/HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#CharacterLabel {margin-right:110px}
#ActionLabel {margin-right:125px}
#NumOfDiceLabel {margin-right:60px}
#SidesLabel {margin-right:20px}

</style>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<p><label id="CharacterLabel" for="CharacterInput">Character:</label> 
<label id="ActionLabel" for="ActionInput">Action:</label>
<label id="NumOfDiceLabel" for="NumDice">Number of Dice:</label>
<label id="SidesLabel" for="Sides">Sides:</label>
<label id="BonusLabel" for="BonusInput">Bonus:</label></p>
<p><input type="text" name="Character" id="CharacterInput" />
<input type="text" name="Action" id="ActionInput" />
<input type="text" name="NumberOfDice" id="NumDice" />
<select id="Sides">
 <option value="3">d3</option>
 <option value="4">d4</option>
 <option value="6">d6</option>
 <option value="8">d8</option>
 <option value="10">d10</option>
 <option value="12">d12</option>
 <option value="20" select="selected">d20</option>
 <option valoue="100">d100</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="Bonus" id="BonusInput" /></p>
<p><button onclick="rollDice()" style="width:100px; height:50px;">Roll Dice</button></p>
<p><textarea name="Output" id="OutputBox" rows="10" cols="100" readonly="true"/></textarea></p>
<label id="ErrorLog">Message:</label>

<script>

function getXMLHttpRequestObject(){
 var ajaxWork=null;
 if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
  ajaxWork = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else if (window.ActiveXObject){
  ajaxWork = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
 }
 return ajaxWork;
}

function callAjax(ajaxWork)
{
 ajaxWork.open('GET', 'http://coldrepublic.com/log.txt', true);
 ajaxWork.send(null)
}

function writeToLog(toLog)
{
 var data = new FormData();
     data.append("data",toLog);
 
 var xhr = getXMLHttpRequestObject();
 xhr.open( 'POST', 'http://coldrepublic.com/writeToLog.php', true );

 xhr.send(data);
}

function myFunction(){

 var ajaxWork = getXMLHttpRequestObject();

 ajaxWork.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(ajaxWork.readyState == 4){
   if((ajaxWork.status >=200 && ajaxWork.status < 300)
   || (ajaxWork.status == 304)){
    document.getElementById('OutputBox').value = ajaxWork.responseText;
   
   }
   else{
    document.getElementById('ErrorLog').innerHTML = "Message: Error! Did not properly read file";
   }
  }
 }
 
 callAjax(ajaxWork);
}

function rollDice(){
 var character = document.getElementById("CharacterInput").value;
 var action = document.getElementById("ActionInput").value;
 var sides = parseInt(document.getElementById("Sides").value);
 var diceRolls = "";
 var toLog = "";
 
 var OutputBox = document.getElementById('OutputBox');

 document.getElementById('ErrorLog').innerHTML = 'Message:';

 var bonusBlank = document.getElementById("BonusInput").value;

 if(character == null || character == "",action == null || action == "")
 { 

  document.getElementById('ErrorLog').innerHTML = 'Message: Error! Must enter value for Character or Action.';
 }
 else
 {
  if(isInt(parseInt(document.getElementById("NumDice").value)) && isInt(parseInt(document.getElementById("BonusInput").value)))
  {
   var numDice = parseInt(document.getElementById("NumDice").value);
   var bonus = document.getElementById("BonusInput").value;

    for (i=0; i < numDice; i++)
   {
    var numTemp = Math.floor(Math.random() * sides) +1;
    var strTemp = numTemp.toString();
    diceRolls = diceRolls.concat(" " + strTemp);
   }
  
   var outTemp = "";
   var outTemp = outTemp.concat();
   var dateTemp = timeStamp();
   
   toLog = character + " " + action + " " + diceRolls + " Bonus: " + bonus + " Timestamp: " + dateTemp + "\n" ;
   writeToLog(toLog);
   location.reload();
   location.reload();
  }
  else
  {
   if(bonusBlank == null || bonusBlank == "")
   {
    var numDice = parseInt(document.getElementById("NumDice").value);
    var bonus = 0;

     for (i=0; i < numDice; i++)
    {
     var numTemp = Math.floor(Math.random() * sides) +1;
     var strTemp = numTemp.toString();
     diceRolls = diceRolls.concat(" " + strTemp);
    }
  
    var outTemp = "";
    var outTemp = outTemp.concat();
    var dateTemp = timeStamp();
    
    toLog = character + " " + action + " " + diceRolls + " Bonus: " + bonus + " Timestamp: " + dateTemp + "\n";
    writeToLog(toLog);
    location.reload();
    location.reload();
   }
   else
   {
    document.getElementById('ErrorLog').innerHTML = 'Message: Error! Entered non-integer value for Number of Dice or Bonus.';
   }
  }
 }
}

function isInt(value) {
  return !isNaN(value) && 
         parseInt(Number(value)) == value && 
         !isNaN(parseInt(value, 10));
}

function timeStamp(){
 // Create a date object with the current time
   var now = new Date();

 // Create an array with the current month, day and time
   var date = [ now.getMonth() + 1, now.getDate(), now.getFullYear() ];

 // Create an array with the current hour, minute and second
   var time = [ now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds() ];

 // Determine AM or PM suffix based on the hour
   var suffix = ( time[0] < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";

 // Convert hour from military time
   time[0] = ( time[0] < 12 ) ? time[0] : time[0] - 12;

 // If hour is 0, set it to 12
   time[0] = time[0] || 12;

 // If seconds and minutes are less than 10, add a zero
   for ( var i = 1; i < 3; i++ ) {
     if ( time[i] < 10 ) {
        time[i] = "0" + time[i];
     }
  }

 // Return the formatted string
   return date.join("/") + " " + time.join(":") + " " + suffix;
 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just tried in firefox and it seems like it's working, though the GET request 304's intermittently.

Comment: please re-check my additions to answer (not sure if you receive notifications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't payed a lot of attention for what your code does but I think I know what the problem is and if my solution is correct I'm going to add few other thoughts about your code.

Your code works in Chrome because Chrome works faster than any other browser and it's able to execute your xhr call before it calls for page reload (actually that's just a luck that it's working in Chrome, and on some machines results may differ so it may be working in other browsers or not working at all). To make it work in any other browser you need to add callback to your xhr call and execute `location.reload();` inside callback.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

```
function writeToLog(toLog)
{
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("data",toLog);

    var xhr = getXMLHttpRequestObject();
    xhr.open( 'POST', 'http://coldrepublic.com/writeToLog.php', true );

    xhr.onload = function (e) {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          console.log('ok');
          location.reload();
        } else {
          console.error('problem');
        }
      }
    };

    xhr.send(data);
}
```

don't forget to remove `location.reload();` from other places in `rollDice`

```
        toLog = character + " " + action + " " + diceRolls + " Bonus: " + bonus + " Timestamp: " + dateTemp + "\n" ;
        writeToLog(toLog);
    }
```

`EDIT:`
Since main problem was resolved here are few other suggestions

`character == null`

those values came from input and inputs store strings so they never will be null values, only `character == ""` should be enough

what you doing here

`if(character == null || character == "",action == null || action == "")`

is wrong, you using comma operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator instead of just another `OR` (`||`)

`isInt(parseInt(document.getElementById("NumDice").value)`

is too extensive `parseInt` returns either NaN or Number, so

```
function isInt(value) {
  return !isNaN(value) && 
     parseInt(Number(value)) == value && 
     !isNaN(parseInt(value, 10));
}
```

makes no sense.

`if (!isNaN(NaN))` is same as `if (NaN)`

`parseInt(Number(value)) == value` again makes no sense here since you already passing result of parseInt to it (`isInt(parseInt(document.getElementById("NumDice").value))`)

and same here `!isNaN(parseInt(value, 10));` if it's number it will be number at any radix, and if it's NaN it's always will be a NaN

---

`if (parseInt(document.getElementById("NumDice").value)...` should already be enough to check that valid number was entered (0 is valid too so you may also want to add `> 0` check)

if you want to check that `1` wasn't converted from `1sdfsdf` only then you might want to add

```
var numdice = document.getElementById("NumDice").value; 
if (numdice == parseInt(numdice)...
```

Comment: I added in/edited the code with your recommendations! Thanks again for the pointers, I wont lie. A lot of this was me googling how other people did it.